# Storing multiple images in database: Second image extension is not stored

Tags: php, html, sql

So I have a form that stores username, profession, image and image1.

Now, username, profession and image are stored in the database. But image2's name is stored without its extension and I cant figure out why its doing this.

[image]

```
    <?php

    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];// user name
        $userjob = $_POST['user_job'];// user email

        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];

        $imgFile1 = $_FILES['user_image1']['name'];
        $tmp_dir1 = $_FILES['user_image1']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize1 = $_FILES['user_image1']['size'];


        if(empty($username)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Username.";
        }
        else if(empty($userjob)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Your Job Work.";
        }
        else if(empty($imgFile or $imgFile1)){
            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
            $imgExt1 = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile1,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
            $userpic1 = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt1;


            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }


            else if(in_array($imgExt1, $valid_extensions)){
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize1 < 5000000)             {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir1,$upload_dir.$userpic1);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }


            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            }



        }


        // if no error occured, continue ....
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userProfession,userPic,userPic1) VALUES(:uname, :ujob, :upic, :upic1)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ujob',$userjob);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic1',$userpic1);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:5;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Upload, Insert, Update, Delete an Image using PHP MySQL - Coding Cage</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com" title='Programming Blog'>Coding Cage</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/CRUD">CRUD</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/PDO">PDO</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/jQuery">jQuery</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">


    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="h2">add new user. <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> &nbsp; view all </a></h1>
    </div>


    <?php
    if(isset($errMSG)){
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <strong><?php echo $errMSG; ?></strong>
            </div>
            <?php
    }
    else if(isset($successMSG)){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $successMSG, $imgExt1; ?></strong>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>   

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Username.</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Profession(Job).</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_job" placeholder="Your Profession" value="<?php echo $userjob; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Profile Img.</label></td>
        <td><input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image" accept="image/*" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Profile Img2.</label></td>
        <td><input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image1" accept="image/*" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; save
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>

</form>



<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>tutorial link !</strong> <a href="http://www.codingcage.com/2016/02/upload-insert-update-delete-image-using.html">Coding Cage</a>!
</div>



</div>






<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This: `$_FILES['user_image']['name1'];` looks wrong. Do a `var_dump($_FILES['user_image])` and see what array looks like.

Comment: Also, make sure you have error reporting turned on (preferably also `display_errors` while you develop) and check your log files for eventual error messages.

Comment: It should of course be: `var_dump($_FILES['user_image'])`

Comment: After you set `$imgext1`, echo it to make sure it's right. Is it right?

Comment: just tried to echo $imgext1, nothing outputted

Comment: Have you dumped the `$_FILES`-variable to see what it actually contains?

Comment: And doing the same thing for $imgExt gives a proper extension?

Comment: I got it to work. name1 and tmp_name1 needed to be name  and tmp_name.  $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); needs $_FILES['user_image']['name']; to find the extension. I hope that makes sense. Sorry for the hassle. I'll correct the code so you can see what I mean

Comment: formatting, typo, spelling